# OData without IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, ado.net-entity-data-model

I’m thinking of using OData for my web service (based on Web API). Unfortunately, my datasource is NOT IQueryable. Instead of implementing my own IQueryable I pretty much followed [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/25/translating-odata-queries-to-hql.aspx).

What I don’t understand is how to get to my entity data model (EDM)? Do I have to model an EDM for example in the Designer? Or is this for EF only and I can use „plain“ classes instead and set relation-attributes? I don’t want to expose my internal data structures therefore my EDM is more like DTOs...

In an [example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/getting-started-with-odata-in-web-api/create-a-read-only-odata-endpoint) I’ve seen that I‘m supposed to derive from EntitySetController in order to get the OData-compliant HTTP response. I believe I can’t use EntitySetController as I don’t support IQueryable. What am I supposed to do in order to get a proper response anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build an EDM model yourself. You can use the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` class to build your EDM model. This [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/getting-started-with-odata-in-web-api/create-a-read-only-odata-endpoint) has some sample code. 
Also, checkout the samples on OData from [here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/), especially the ODataServiceSample and ODataCompositeKeySample. They should get you started.

Also, if you do not have an `IQueryable`, you could derive from `ODataController` instead of `EntitySetController`.